# Abstract characterization of dihedral group

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

I am looking at the proof of theorem 1.1 of [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf) notes on dihedral groups, which states the following:

> Let $G$ be generated by elements $x$ and $y$ where $x^n = 1$ for some $n \geq 3$, $y^2 = 1$, and $yxy^{−1} = x^{−1}$. There is a surjective
> homomorphism $D_n \to G$, and if $G$ has order $2n$ then this
> homomorphism is an isomorphism.

Suppose the the two generators of the dihedral group are $r$ and $s$, with orders $n$ and 2, respectively. In the proof the author defines the function $f(r^js^k) = x^jy^k$ and states the following:

> This function makes sense, since the only ambiguity in writing an element of $D_n$ as $r^js^k$ is that $j$ can change modulo $n$ and $k$
> can change modulo $2$, which has no effect on the right side since $x^n=1$ and $y^2 = 1$.

I fail to see why this proves it is well defined. In particular, I cannot see why this implies that if I write the same element of $D_n$ with different representations then the image of both will coincide. For example, in the dihedral group $rsr = s$, but why can we affirm that $f(rsr) = f(s)$?

Comment: The paragraph that you quoted only defines $f$ on elements of the form $r^js^k$. It does not define $f(rsr)$ explicitly. So your objection does not apply at this point. Or to put it another way, the author is not attempting to prove in this particular paragraph that $f(rsr) = f(s)$.

Comment: That is true, but in the paragraphs that follow the one I mentioned the author proceeds to prove that the function is in fact an homomorphism. How can we assure then that it is a well defined mapping?

Comment: This depends on the way that the author has defined the group $D_n$. I don't know exactly what that is, but the author seems to be assuming the stated property that "the only ambiguity in writing an element of $D_n$ as $r^js^k$ ..." holds in the group $D_n$. If you accept that, then the map $f$ is well-defined. Once we agree that it is well-defined then $f(srs) = f(s)$ holds because $rsr = s$. The issue here is about the group $D_n$ itself, not about the definition of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point is that every element of $D_n$ looks like $r^js^k$. So it suffices to (i) describe $f$ on elements of $D_n$ when written that way and (ii) check if you write the same element as $r^js^k$ with different pairs of exponents, the resulting values of $x^jy^k$ are the same. That shows $f$ is well-defined on $D_n$.  The file has been updated to clarify these points.